# Multi-level / mixed-effect / hierarchical linear regression. Model and interpretation advice?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, interaction, multilevel-analysis

I want to run and then report a multi-level model on the ChickWeight data in R.

I have done several analyses of which I have a few questions. I've been told the AIC is a good way to test a model's predictive out-of-sample performance.

I have considered the following models, and the bottom one has the lowest AIC, which if i'm not wrong, is a good thing?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
data("ChickWeight", package = "datasets")

chickm <- lmer(weight ~ Time + (1 | Chick), data = ChickWeight)
chickm2 <- lmer(weight ~ Time + (Time | Chick), data = ChickWeight)
chickm3 <- lmer(weight ~ Time + Diet + (Time | Chick), data = ChickWeight)
chickm4 <- lmer(weight ~ Time * Diet + (Time | Chick), data = ChickWeight)
```

I want to report chickm4 since the interaction effect seems to improve the model. However chickm3 would also be acceptable since I would like Diet in there.

Next question is about the intercept that the model(s) produce. The actual intercept (weight of chick when days = 0 aka it is born, is ~ 41g). Yet chickm3 gives the intercept as 26g and chickm4 as 33g. You can see in the graph below that the linear lines-of-best-fit cause this. The intercepts of the lines are all below the true points.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Time, y = weight, colour = Diet)) + geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', se = F) + theme_minimal()
```

Is this a problem or an example of a bad model, or just a downside to the data and/or linear models compared to non-linear models? I do have to report a multi-level *linear* regression though, so I can't change this.

Final question. chickm3 shows *'Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00225537 (tol = 0.002, component 1)'* when I summary() it. What does this mean and is it bad? My chickm4 model doesn't do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of points:

- These models are nested and therefore you can also use formal hypothesis testing using F-test to compare them. These F-test are provided by the **lmerTest** package.
- In general it is not good to *only* look at measures like AIC or p-values to decide which terms to include in the model, especially the fixed effects in this case. You should also see how substantive is the difference between the additive model `chickm3` and the interaction model `chickm4`. You could more easily assess this using an effects plots - see, e.g., the **effects** or **ggeffects** packages.
- Indeed the effect that the intercept of the model does not correspond to the average value you have for `Time` equal to zero and `Diet` equal to the reference level is because you fit a line, and the estimate of the slope also affects the estimate of the intercept. You could mitigate this affect but fitting a nonlinear model for the `Time` variable using, e.g., splines.
- Finally, regarding the convergence warning message, you could ignore it in this case because it is very close to the tolerance value.

Answer (score 3):

I've made a few example models which should be nested if you just test them in order. The model I believe best is chickm6 which:

- removes the baseline Time 0 Diet effect, which is intuitive since at Time 0 (I would imagine at birth), the Diet should not have any effect on chick weight
- added a linear two-piece spline, with the knot placed at Time 6 (somewhat determined by eyeballing the loess curve). This allows the modelled baseline Time 0 response (39.8) to be much closer to observed mean weight (41), while keeping the model simple, explainable and still linear. Of course you may try with more knots.

[image]

```
library(stats)
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
data("ChickWeight", package = "datasets")

ChickWeight <- as_tibble(ChickWeight) %>%
  mutate(Time_6p = pmax(0, Time - 6))

chickm4 <- lmer(weight ~ Time * Diet + (Time | Chick), data = ChickWeight)
chickm5 <- lmer(weight ~ Time + Time_6p + Time:Diet + (Time | Chick), data = ChickWeight)
chickm6 <- lmer(weight ~ Time + Time_6p + Time:Diet + Time_6p:Diet + (Time | Chick), data = ChickWeight)
chickm7 <- lmer(weight ~ Time*Diet + Time_6p*Diet + (Time | Chick), data = ChickWeight)

anova(chickm4, chickm5, chickm6, chickm7) # not sure if it actually does a refit with ML

pred_df <- ChickWeight %>%
  distinct(Time, Time_6p, Diet) %>%
  mutate(pred4 = predict(chickm4, newdata = ., re.form = ~0)) %>%
  mutate(pred6 = predict(chickm6, newdata = ., re.form = ~0))

ChickWeight %>%
  mutate(Chick = forcats::fct_reorder(as.character(Chick), sample(row_number()))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Time)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = weight, color = Chick)) + 
  geom_line(data = pred_df, aes(y = pred4, linetype = 'pred4'), size = 1) +
  geom_line(data = pred_df, aes(y = pred6, linetype = 'pred6'), size = 1) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y = weight), method = 'loess') +
  scale_color_discrete(guide = FALSE) +
  facet_wrap(~Diet)
```

Comment: thanks @user3408956 i really appreciate the time you put into this. The thing is this is related to my course work and whilst i understand why the weight of the chick between 0 to ~6 days isnt much affected by Diet, and your 'knotted' line is much better, I don't have the skills to do these sorts of plots (nor is it currently expected of me, hence why I unfortunately can't really use the great graph you've produced.) I suppose the best thing for me to do is point out the limitations of my chickm4 model, which is presumably the poor intercept and poor predictions for Time between 0 and 6, ish?